# Can I ask for websites about child safety with scientific or high quality anecdotal links?

Tags: discussion, research

For example look at WebMD- some pages are reviewed by a doctor but those doctors didn't bother to require them to include citations or demonstrative documentaries/ case studies. I tried look at Waldorf- supposedly a Child research institute which has a lot of articles that are rambling and vague.

Can I ask for other sites like this here?

Comment: To make it on-topic, consider asking a more practical, problem-oriented question, for example "What are risks associated with my child cycling outside?", or "How can I determine whether medical advice on a website is credible?".

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by sleske, we aren't a search function for other online resources. Instead, this is a good site to ask specific questions on child safety, with members of the community ranging from medical professionals to first time expectant parents.

Medical advice as such is off topic here (you'd want to speak to a doctor anyway, not rely on anything on the Internet) but we do have guidance posts the include aspects of medical advice where appropriate.

Comment: Search engines are worthless.